# What is a good way to display the time in multiple time zones in Windows?

Tags: windows, time-zone

I've just started on a project which will involve working with people in mulitple time zones.

I was wondering what was a good way for me to display the time in up to four time zones.  I don't need them visible all the time but I would like to see all the time zones at the same time without too many clicks.

I guess I need either a good world clock application or recommendations of good desktop widgets.

**Edit:** I have Windows 7 at home but XP on my work PC so an solution that works for XP would be helpful.

Comment: You haven't written which version of Windows you're using. Vista and 7 have this functionality built-in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Vista (or Windows 7), the built-in clock widget allows you to set a different time zone per instance, and give it a name.  So, for example, you could set an instance to Sydney time, and name it "Sydney", and it will show the name on the clock itself.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked the [Kybtec World Clock](http://kybtec.de/wbx01/ssh01/Home/HomeX01.htm?adv=gog01&advs=non&way=adv&diff=c_us_01_ad02a&kw=desktop_world_clock&gclid=CJDiwZid5lMCFSZcSgod-Bz7YA). It's very customizable.

Comment: I really liked this but I don't think it's worth $49. If it were more like $10 I think I would have bought a copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing Yahoo Widgets (formerly Konfabulator) then [this widget](http://widgets.yahoo.com/widgets/world-clock-pro) looks pretty sexy:

[image]

Comment: They do look nice.  However, I have Google Desktop installed and I couldn't do without the search facility it provides and installing two Gadget Frameworks worries me.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Zone Tick](http://zonetick.com/) here, and it does the job just fine

Answer (score 1):

Being as though you have Google Desktop installed, try the [Time Around the World gadget](http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/timezone.html?start=20).

[image]

Comment: It's nice - especially the auto zoom where it's small until you point the mouse at it - but there's no way of telling if the time is AM or PM and calling someone in the middle of night is precisely the problem I am trying to avoid.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 allows you to add additional clocks to the Date and Time display on the Taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed me in the direction of [NovaClock](http://www.novaclock.de/).

It looks nice, is very customisable and can show multiple time zones.

Unfortunately, on my laptop it crashes whenever I try to load one of my saved customisations.  However, I thought I'd post it as this may be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Another one of my colleages uses this [Java Applet at www.timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/personalapplet.html).

It remembers the cities chosen so if you have a shortcut to the page on your desktop it's one click to view times in the various cities.